# Array of inconsistent types in typescript

Tags: typescript

Given array of inconsistent types. This may be used to dynamically rendering of html elements for example.

```
interface IElement {
  type: 'button' | 'input'
  content: Button & Input
}

interface Button {
  text?: string;
  backgroundColor?: string;
}

interface Input {
  value?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
}

const elements: IElement[] = [
  {
    type: 'button',
    content: {
      text: 'Start',
      backgroundColor: 'salmon'
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'input',
    content: {
      value: 'phone',
      placeholder: 'Phone'
    }
  }
]

const newElement = elements.map(element => element.content.backgroundColor)
```

Is there any other ways to typecast it properly depends on `type` property without union?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Typescript the standard pattern is to use what is called a "discriminated union". Basically, where in other languages you would work with `IElement` values, in Typescript you try to work with a union instead. This allows Typescript to determine the proper type when you check the value of the `type` field in a type guard.

It might look something like this:

```
interface Button {
  type: 'button'
  text: string
  backgroundColor: string
}

interface Input {
  type: 'input'
  value: string
  placeholder: string
}

type ElementUnion = Button | Input

const elements: ElementUnion[] = [
  {
    type: 'button',
    text: 'Start',
    backgroundColor: 'salmon'
  },
  {
    type: 'input',
    value: 'phone',
    placeholder: 'Phone'
  }
]

function doSomething (el: ElementUnion) {
  if (el.type === 'button') {
    console.log(el.text) // TS knows this is Button
  } else if (el.type === 'input') {
    console.log(el.placeholder) // TS knows this is Input
  }
}
```

Note that I haven't defined any of the properties as optional or as an intersection, however Typescript still lets me use them in `doSomething` as long as I check the `type` field first. This is the power of a discriminated union.

And if you wish, you can still use the inheritance pattern at the same time:

```
type ElementType = 'button' | 'input'

interface IElement {
  type: ElementType
  content: unknown
}

interface Button extends IElement {
  type: 'button'
  content: {
    text: string
    backgroundColor: string
  }
}

interface Input extends IElement {
  type: 'input'
  content: {
    value: string
    placeholder: string
  }
}

type ElementUnion = Button | Input
    
function doSomething (el: ElementUnion) {
  if (el.type === 'button') {
    console.log(el.content.text) // TS knows this is Button
  } else if (el.type === 'input') {
    console.log(el.content.placeholder) // TS knows this is Input
  }
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogNhAthAdsAKuaBeKByAIwFdhgB7FPKAH3wEsUwS8AoFh4CAJwDMBDAMbQAkvCSpgUAN4soUUJABcsBMjSZIsqAIqc0yoigDWKMgHcULAL5sO3fkKgAhEuRRQIADz0ATAM5QoqoS0loKEMqErhSscjpoEsoycnKc3sp%20wFwMAOZacgSCRjlcZIY%20AMJkcGRcGVm5WjY27Am8giKMJB7eqP6BYmqSyfJYkQxMwLHauomhKVAAbnxwRBFQmdkoeQtgcB0AFtU%203PVbO1DNbOEq4mgAqih0FFC4LqQvtMJdwGzxmR5gmg-MpBhJHs8UABtAC6rygUK0I1SY3wxA%20lAANPkZgl9PMFvIvMBIgBlYB8LhTbGEqCFATFUrlKo1Or4PwrRAxHE2ORWGkElFKeg-PACuKzfHIlLLVbrPBgI4oCBinFyPaHY6nfAABSVKp5TRYMLYPEMAmAkKgPjIpLIyGAB1yUAAFBA4KCgcAIRQAJQEug8V3ugB0N2wEbR0Uo-ul-2qEBDNRybrgIfiemAYeJ-oA9LmoOhSVATOYAo66AFK85o01AX5oIHg2nw5G8BNmLGcfGEEmyCnQxmJCGNUIjnATlw8wWiyXTGZy06qwFvpMjTYgA)

Comment: Why not use generics. this looks complicated and tightly coupled??

Comment: @Sohan you need a union in order to have `content` typed properly. In your generic answer you are forced to define `content: T1 & T2`  and then set all the actual content properties as optional. That's not type safe.

Comment: This is right but the base interface `IElement` doesn't serve any purpose and might cause confusion

Comment: @AluanHaddad it can be useful to enforce type of the discriminator as `ElementType`. Also there could be code that depends on a common shape for these objects and if one doesn't match then you may want the error to be reported at point of the definition rather than use.

Comment: I agree it definitely can be useful. Anyway, I appreciate that added clarification about its optionality. A very strong answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `type`:

```
type IElement = {
  type: 'button'
  content: Button
} | {
  type: 'input'
  content: Input
}
```

I don't know how to do it with `interface`.

Comment: Haven't tried this one yet, but this syntax looks short and concise, I like it. Hopefully it works with loops well.

Comment: Unfortunately, this way doesn't work with loops in IDE

Answer (score -1):

If you ask me do to proper type, i would go with [Typescript Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Hers is the sample,

```
interface IElement<T> {
    type: string,
    content: T
}

interface Button {
    text?: string;
    backgroundColor?: string;
}

interface Input {
    value?: string;
    placeholder?: string;
}

const elements: IElement<Button>[] = [
    {
        type: 'button',
        content: {
            text: 'Start',
            backgroundColor: 'salmon'
        }
    }
]
const newElement = elements.map(element => element.content.backgroundColor);
```

If you are looking for extension with multiple classes and merge,

```
interface IElement<T1 , T2> {
    type: string,
    content: T1 & T2
}

interface Button {
    text?: string;
    backgroundColor?: string;
}

interface Input {
    value?: string;
    placeholder?: string;
}

const elements: IElement<Button,Input>[] = [
    {
        type: 'button',
        content: {
            text: 'Start',
            backgroundColor: 'salmon'
        }
    },
    {
        type: 'input',
        content: {
            value: 'phone',
            placeholder: 'Phone'
        }
    }
]
const newElement = elements.map(element => element.content.backgroundColor);
```